# how to reload the usercontrol in the master page with effecting other part of the master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a master page. In that master page i have a user control which holds a Label control, it shows data read from a text file using marquee.
My text file changes every 2 minutes so I want to reload my user control every 2 minutes without effecting the master page.

How can i do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the user control in an UpdatePanel and refresh the contents via an AsyncPostBack trigger as described in the following article:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

Answer (score 0):

Here is one sluggish solution:

put the `label` control in a new page (with no master page) and add a `timer` with that label to refresh every 1 minute or so.

Now, go back to your master page and add an `iframe` with `SRC` pointing to the new page you created before. This way, all the refresh effect will be limited to the iframe only and not to your master page.

*Edit: you don't need a timer for the page inside the iframe. Just set the META refresh time period to whatever you want and in the code behind of that page, let the Page_Load event populate the label

Comment: This does sound a little... 1980s for my taste

Answer (score 0):

UpdatePanel and use a Timer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx